# docker-machine ssh trying to run part of command on local machine

Tags: bash, docker, docker-machine

When running the following command:

```
docker-machine ssh name-here "docker swarm init --advertise-addr $(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')"
```

I get the following error:

> hostname: illegal option -- I
>   usage: hostname [-fs] [name-of-host]

This is because the command is attempting to run `hostname -I` on my local machine, running on MacOS, which doesn't have a `-I` flag.

*Attempting to run without double quotes gives the same error.*

I encapsulated the full command in double quotes so my expectation would be that the full contents of the double quotes is executed as a single argument to `docker-machine ssh`, but it seems that this is not the case.

I've tried single quotes (`'`) but this interferes with awk's single quote requirement around the print. I even tried the crazy `$$` as you would use in makefiles next to the hostname but this doesn't work either.

Why is `$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')` being executed on the host machine when the command is encapsulated in double quotes, and how can I run the above command correctly to initialise a docker swarm with the hostname within the machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `man bash`:

> Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $, `, \, and, when history expansion is enabled, !. The characters $ and` retain their special meaning within double quotes. The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: $, `, ", \, or . A double quote may be quoted within double quotes by preceding it with a backslash. If enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an ! appearing in double quotes is escaped using a backslash. The backslash preceding the ! is not removed.

So with this in mind, the following works:

`docker-machine ssh name-here 'docker swarm init --advertise-addr $(hostname -I | awk '\'{print \$1}\'')'`

Note how the `$1` in print is escaped with a `\`, and one set of single quotes are also escaped around print.

Answer (score 1):

[Command substitutions](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) within double quotes are always executed "immediately", that is, as part of Bash expanding the command. What you need to do to quote a command substitution is use *single* quotes. Compare double quotes (local substitution):

```
$ bash --noprofile --norc -o xtrace
bash-4.4$ ssh 127.0.0.1 "echo ${SSH_CONNECTION-No SSH connection}"
+ ssh 127.0.0.1 'echo No SSH connection'
No SSH connection
```

And single quotes (remote substitution):

```
bash-4.4$ ssh 127.0.0.1 'echo ${SSH_CONNECTION-No SSH connection}'
+ ssh 127.0.0.1 'echo ${SSH_CONNECTION-No SSH connection}'
127.0.0.1 59618 127.0.0.1 22
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried single quotes but I couldn’t get them working with awk as described. Any chance you could shape this to the context of my specific awk problem? Thanks :-)

Comment: OK, so you basically have a triple-nested command. What you'll want to do is `printf '%q'` each level of the command separately (starting with the `awk` argument and going outwards) to manage to escape it all.